# Using files as SQL tables

Tags: c#, winforms

I have CSV files which basically are tables from SQL database. They have following content:

> ColumnName1,name2,name3
>
> Value1,value2,value3
>
> Value1,value2,value3

File naming is following: `tablename` (no extension)

I have 10 such tables. How is it possible to merge such files? Is it maybe possible to somehow use SQL commands such as join, where, or, and.. Etc..?

I can load them separately into arrays using the hardcode. I can use if, else statements to hardcode joins and wheres. What I am asking here - is an advice how to operate such tables in an easier way.

My main goal is to merge tables and filter the result. Result will probably be displayed in datagridview.

I am planning on using this tool at work, so only free of charge (free license, open source) libraries or tools are currently sought.

Comment: If you can get these to a dataset it could do what it sounds like you want to do.

Comment: You could try Microsoft's OLE DB Provider. It accepts CSV file path in connection string. More info: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/connect-to-csv-data-files-using-microsoft-data-access-components.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have 10 "tables" with the same schema, since you want to merge them.
In that case I'd create a struct like

```
public struct Line {
    int Column1;
    string Column2;
    float Column3;
}
```

Then I'd populate a List with the content of the file(s). You can then use LINQ (which is similar to SQL) very easily on this data structure. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397900.aspx) is a good walkthrough for using queries on lists of structs.